# Updating Cursor on SQLite database change

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, android-sqlite

This is my scenario:

**Activity 1**, Is where I have a list with items.

**Activity 1** contains an object of **Class A**, which deals with getting and returning a cursor of data retrieved by an SQLite database, via a Loader Manager set up, to **Activity 1**.

In **Activity 1**, Each of these views within the list have buttons. When pressing a button,
**Class B** is executed.

**Class B** changes a single value within the SQLite database.

In **Class B**, How can I notify the Loader Manager that the data has changed, for it to refresh the cursor. Remember, The Loader Manager is set up in **Class A**.

Essentially, If the above didn't make sense,
I need to refresh the cursor as the underlying sql data has changed, but I need to do this from a class that has not a direct connection to the loader manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both classes have access to each other , say in your onCreate in Activity1

```
ClassA obj1 = new ClassA(...);
ClassB obj2 = new ClassB(...);
obj2.setClasssA(obj1);
```

and inside your ClassB code, after you're done with updating the db you can just call a method in classA to update the cursor.
something a long the line of :

```
obj1.onNewData();
```

I hope that makes sense

Comment: A great concept! But how exactly will this work with a Loader, as in this scenario, ClassA is a Custom Loader and the Activity1 is extending LoaderManager. Any ideas?

Comment: once your onNewData method is called, you will have direct access to your loaderManager object.
If this doesn't seem right to you please post your classes source code